# sqlite3 fts3 multiple columns search including special characters

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, multiple-columns

i am using sqlite3 fts3. (sqlite3 version is 3.7.17)

I tried to search keywords including special characters (ex. @, ?) in multiple columns.

This is my examples.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_name MATCH 
'EMAIL:aaa@test.com OR SUBJECT:is it a question?'
```

This query have to return a result having email address is 'aaa@test.com' or subject is 'is it a question?'

But this query is not return correct results.
I think that sqlite3 fts3 can't recognize special characters...

How can i solve this problem? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a [phrase query](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#full_text_index_queries), you must use quotes.

Special characters are filtered out by the default [tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer); `aaa@test.com` must be handled as a phrase with three words.

Comment: I knew what is my problem.

Comment: Thank you so much!!